# Does QuestDB supports Foreign key, Primary key, references?

Tags: questdb

I wonder how db schema design would look, because at first glance I need bunch sql relation features, that are not available out of box in QuestDB.

Answer (score 2):

No, QuestDB does not support PK, FK and any other constraints yet.

Schema can be same as other relational databases, except the PK values have to be generated by the application. QuestDB will not enforce uniqueness of values in a table column and uniqueness has to come from inserting application.